# If two elements from a group are conjugated, their centralizers are as well

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

> I want to show that if two elements $x,y \in G$ are conjugated then their centralizers $Z(x),Z(y) \subseteq G$ are also conjugated.

More formally:

$\exists g \in G: gxg^{-1} = y \rightarrow \exists g \in G: gZ(x)g^{-1} = Z(y)$

My approach is the following: $y \in Z(y) \rightarrow gxg^{-1} \in Z(y) \rightarrow x \in g^{-1}Z(y)g$ and vice versa so that I know that both elements are in the centralizer of each other. But then I don't know how to continue.

Comment: your approach doesn't quite make sense - you need to show that $z\in C(x)$ if and only if $gzg^{-1}\in C(y)$ (also you seem to have use $C$ and $Z$ for centraliser which is normally denoted $C_G$)

Comment: If $f:G\to G$ is an automorphism, then $f(Z(x)) = Z(f(x))$. Your case is $f=c_g$ conjugation by the element $g$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Write $y=gxg^{-1}$ and $u$ in $Z(x)$, $gug^{-1}y=gug^{-1}gxg^{-1}=guxg^{-1}=gxug^{-1}=gxg^{-1}gug^{-1}=ygug^{-1}$ implies that $gug^{-1}$ is in $Z(y)$  and $gZ(x)g^{-1}\subset Z(y)$.

On the other hand, let $v\in Z(y), vyv^{-1}=y$ is equivalent to $vgxg^{-1}v^{-1}=gxg^{-1}$ and $g^{-1}vgxg^{-1}v^{-1}g=x$, write $u=g^{-1}vg$, you deduce that $u\in Z(x)$. This implies that $v=gug^{-1}\in gZ(x)g^{-1}$ and you deduce that $Z(y)\subset gZ(x)g^{-1}$.

Comment: I think you could've shortened it just by chain of equivalences: $$\begin{aligned}h\in\mathcal C_G(y)&\Leftrightarrow hy=yh\\&\Leftrightarrow hgxg^{-1}=gxg^{-1}h\\&\Leftrightarrow g^{-1}hgx=xg^{-1}hg\\&\Leftrightarrow g^{-1}hg\in\mathcal  C_G(x)\\&\Leftrightarrow h\in g\mathcal C_G(x)g^{-1}\end{aligned}$$

Answer (score 0):

More generally, consider a group $G$ acting on some set $X$. The stabilizer of $x\in X$ is $$\text{stab}(x) = \{ g\in G : gx=x\}$$ that is, the set of group elements that fix $X$ (in your case let $G=X$ and let $G$ act on itself by conjugation.) Then we always have that

$$\text{stab}(gx) = {}^g \text{stab}(x) $$ where ${}^g(?) = g^{-1}(?)g$ means conjugation. Indeed, an element $h$ fixes $gx$ if and only if $g^{-1}hg$ fixes $x$, hence the result.